# Как отследить наличее AppBar при роутинге

Tags: flutter

Как отследить наличее AppBar при роутинге? Мне нужно вызывать setSystemUIOverlayStyle когда appBar отсутствует на странице.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.